# How to parse and convert local DART configuration file to objects in dart / flutter on windows

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, parsing, local

(Windows platform)
I have a complex local configuration file (dart file) full of objects and enums etc I'd like to parse and load as objects.

Note: The data is full of nested complex objects I don't want to spend 10 years trying to convert to JSON with no benefit and possibly ending "unserializably"

So basically the program loads, opens its default configuration file:
loadedConfig = default embedded config.

I want to read/write/maintain a local dart asset file and load the contents as loadedConfig.

There is plenty of info handing to/from JSON but there is no apparent info on loading a simple dart(txt) file and deserializing it into dart objects?? The closest I've found is storing simple numbers or lists of strings.

Really makes sense to have a local dart file as a config file on a static platform.

Anyone with the wisdom on how to do this or a better unrelated approach? Cheers.

Comment: This is not trivial.  You say "simple dart(txt) file", but a Dart file can contain arbitrary code.  You'd either need to bundle a Dart compiler or VM or restrict yourself to some basic types (e.g. `int`, `String`, `List`, `Map`, ...), at which point you might as well use JSON.

Comment: No, as a config file it contains no arbitrary code. Its a list of objects that make references to existing objects inside the app - enums, strings, objects. If it can already be done with JSON data and mapped to dart objects, it is surely possible to deserialize and interpret a dart file exactly as a dart file in the context of the app?

Comment: Yes, but a `.dart` file *can* contain arbitrary Dart code.  What you actually want is some *well-defined subset* of Dart (just as JSON is a subset of JavaScript).  I am not aware of any packages that attempt to do so, though.

Comment: "If it can already be done with JSON data and mapped to dart objects, it is surely possible to deserialize and interpret a dart file exactly as a dart file in the context of the app?" If you're content with `int`, `double`, `String`, `bool`, `List`, and `Map`, then sure.  But again, if you care only about those types, you might as well just use JSON.  If you want to serialize/deserialize other types or want type-safety, then there is no built-in way to do that, hence the need for things like `package:json_serializable` or `package:built_value`.